# When Outlook Scheduled Send goes wrong

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, delay

We think we have seen a bug in the behaviour of Scheduled Send in Outlook. Our user sent an email as normal on Friday evening using the Outlook desktop app on Exchange Online (Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO). The email did not arrive with internal or external recipients and this was noticed. The email was sitting happily in the Sent Items folder but did not apparently make it to Exchange Online in any form. Much headscratching ensued internally and the email was sent again (and received normally).

At exactly 8:00 AM on Monday morning the original email was delivered to all recipients. This looks a bit like Scheduled Send behaviour but the user did not select 'Do not deliver before' or 'Scheduled Send' in any email client and states that their PC and phone were turned off at 8:00 AM.

What troubleshooting would you recommend to work out what happened and prevent it from happening again?

*Notes: 'Do not deliver before' only works with Outlook running and puts the delayed message into the Outbox; 'Scheduled Send' works offline and puts the message into Drafts.*

*[General help page on the feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/schedule-send-for-outlook-on-the-web-ec6bf1df-f9ac-4e38-903e-33f623d332b1)*

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur with the specific email or some emails?

And does this issue occur in OWA?

If this is an occasional event, it's suggested that you could check your current network and confirm that it is stable, then try to send the same email to the same recipient to see if the problem persists.

In terms of Outlook desktop client, please refer to the below troubleshooting steps:

1. Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.
2. Considering that it may be caused by the damage of the profile/data file in the Outlook client, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.
3. considering corruption in send/receive settings file may cause this issue, You can try to reset the SRS file to check if there're any differences.(Go to C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook>Rename the Outlook.srs file to Outlook.srs.old>restart Outlook)
4. In addition, antivirus software may conflict with outlook. It is suggested that you could temporarily close your antivirus software and restart outlook to check whether this problem still exists.

Hope to help you!